# Unable to sort list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list which contains lists of tuples and I want to sort these sublists by the second element, which is a number between 0.0 and 10.0.

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = sorted(data[i], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

It is all sorted as I expected it, but one element is not which is:

`<type 'list'>: [('String1', '7.5', '', '', None), ('String2', '7.5', '', '', None), ('String3', '10.0', '', '', None)]`

This list stays like it is above, even though it should have the element with 10.0 in front.

Why does it not sort that line, but all others? Is it because it has 7.5 twice?

Comment: Note that the output from `'7.5' > '10.0'` is different to the output from `7.5 > 10.0`...

Comment: what does your original `data` look like? and what would you like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the values as `float` not as `str`

```
>>> sorted(data[i], key=lambda j: float(j[1]), reverse=True)
[('String3', '10.0', '', '', None), ('String1', '7.5', '', '', None), ('String2', '7.5', '', '', None)]
```

Otherwise as written you are comparing the strings

```
'7.5' > '10.0'
```

which is a [lexicographical comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Answer (score 0):

You want it as `float`

```
data[i] = sorted(data[i], key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data are characters, and

```
>>> "10" < "7"
True
>>>
```

Convert to float, either in your sort comparison function or in your data if that's the right place for it.